# Can't store sum using getBoundingClientRect to variable

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
var finalProductDiv;
var workingsDiv;
var div1x = 0;

setTimeout(function(){ 
   finalProductDiv = document.getElementById('contentContaineriFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('finalProduct');
   workingsDiv = document.getElementById('contentContaineriFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('workings');
   div1x = finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left + finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
 }, 2000);
```

The issue is `div1x` always returns 0.

`finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left` returns 16 and `finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width` returns 690. Both values are correct so why is `div1x` = 0 ? It should be 353 right?

Comment: How exactly are you examining the value of `div1x`?

Comment: Specifically, if you put `console.log(div1x)` **inside** the timer callback (at the end of it), do you see the correct value?

Comment: @Pointy inputting ```div1x``` into console in Chrome. Also a calculation I do later in the code using ```div1x``` returns 0 using console.log

Comment: Well `div1x` won't get a value until 2 seconds after the timer is started. Code immediately following the `setTimeout()` call will run *immediately*; it doesn't wait for the timer to fire.

Comment: @Pointy just tried your suggestion, it returns 0

Comment: Well maybe the elements you're measuring are not populated with content at the time you measure them. If you're getting 0 *inside* the timer handler, that would be the case.

Comment: @Pointy ok yes I think I understand your point, I will try to rejig it later today, thank you

Comment: @pointy thank you, yes moving the assignment of the value to ```div1x``` outside of the timeout worked, I put it in another function that was triggered at the end of the timeout

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where you put console.log to get the value of div1x.

Below demostrate the difference when you put inside vs outside the settimeout.

```js
var finalProductDiv;
var workingsDiv;
var div1x = 0;

setTimeout(() => {
finalProductDiv = document.getElementById('finalProduct');
   workingsDiv = document.getElementById('workings');
   div1x = finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left + finalProductDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
   console.log("Value in settimeout : ", div1x)
   // 
   // You should put codes that requires the value of div1x here
   //
   },2000)
   
   // value of div1x here will be 0 because it's not yet calculated
   console.log("Value outside settimeout : ", div1x)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="finalProduct" style="width: 320px; background-color: 'red'" />
    <div id="workings" style="width: 600px; background-color: 'blue'" />

  </body>
</html>
```